# Unknown field "replicas" org.apache.flink.v1beta1.FlinkDeployment.spec.taskManager

Tags: apache-flink

I am currently using flink-kubernetes-operator-1.1.0 and was deployed successfully in my GKE Cluster using the following command:

```
helm repo add flink-operator-repo https://downloads.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-1.1.0/

helm install flink-kubernetes-operator flink-operator-repo/flink-kubernetes-operator --set webhook.create=false
```

However, when I am trying to create a FlinkDeployment with the following taskManager configuration,

```
spec:
  ...
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "4096m"
      cpu: 2
    replicas: 2
  ...
```

I get the following error message:

```
unknown field "replicas" in org.apache.flink.v1beta1.FlinkDeployment.spec.taskManager
```

When I check the CRD - https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/blob/release-1.1/helm/flink-kubernetes-operator/crds/flinkdeployments.flink.apache.org-v1.yml, I can clearly see that the taskManager may contain the "replicas" with type integer. I am not sure If I missed something here.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find the configuration that spins multiple TaskManagers.

if job.parallelism > flinkConfiguration.taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, it starts launching taskManagers.